# Unable to retrieve Sessions in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, session

Hello Everyone I am implementing an angular app with Node.js running at the backend.I am setting the sessions in angular JS and i have made my own factory for that i am using socket.io in my node js server and also i am routing the app from node.js server. I want to restrict the unauthenticated users from accessing the page but to do i have to retrieve the sessions value in my node.js server which i am unable to do so. i am attaching my code snippets.

**Server.js**

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    var express = require('express');
    var https = require('https');
    var path = require('path');
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'fake-keys/privkey.pem')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'fake-keys/fullchain.pem')),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'fake-keys/chain.pem'))

    };
    var PORT = 9001;
    var HOST = '192.168.1.2';
    app = express();
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));

    server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(PORT, HOST);
    console.log('HTTPS Server listening on %s:%s', HOST, PORT);


    // routes
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,'/index.html'));
    });
    app.get('/Admin', function(req, res) {

        res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,'/view/Admin.html'));
    });

    app.get('/Guest', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,'/view/Guest.html'));
    });
        require('./Signaling-Server.js')(server, function(socket) {
            try {
                var params = socket.handshake.query;
                if (!params.socketCustomEvent) {
                    params.socketCustomEvent = 'custom-message';
                }

                socket.on(params.socketCustomEvent, function(message) {
                    try {
                        socket.broadcast.emit(params.socketCustomEvent, message);
                    } catch (e) {}
                });
            } catch (e) {}
        });
```

**Session Service**

```
var myApp = angular.module('SessionService', []);
myApp.factory('SessionService', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    set: function (key, value) {

      return sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
    },
    get: function () {
      return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    },
    destroy: function () {
      return sessionStorage.removeItem(key);

    }


  };

}])
```

i want to get the session value in my nodejs server so that i can keep track of the users which are authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using sessions i used cookies i set the cookie in my angular js controller code and then in node js server i used cookie-parser to get the cookie!
here is my code just to help someone else
**Controller Code**

```
    var artistControllers=angular.module('artistControllers',['SessionService','ngCookies']);

artistControllers.controller('ListController',['$scope','$http','SessionService', '$cookies', '$cookieStore','$location',function($scope,$http,$cookies, $cookieStore,SessionService,$location)

  {
          $cookieStore.put('username', username);    

  }
}]);
```

**Server Code**

```
 app.get('/Admin', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies :  ", req.cookies.username);
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname,'/view/Admin.html'));
});
```